# PhoneGap javascript reference issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, android-webview

In my PhoneGap Eclipse project I am using jQuery for visual effects by referencing jQuery libraries:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
```

and I am also making remote domain requests in order to display some information from the remote server.

1: When I make requests to multiple servers, I get an error saying:

> DroidGap: TIMEOUT ERROR! - calling webViewClient

I read that I must alter my Phonegaps whitelist by doing:

```
<phonegap>
    <access origin="\*\" /> 
</phonegap>
```

Source: [GitHub call-back](https://github.com/callback/callback-android/issues/8)

*But I get some error*, so I have decided to approach same results from the different ways:

2: `<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/jquery.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>`

> Why? - because i would like to avoid getting errors with multiple-domain requests

In these cases I get an error

> **SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///...** in logcat

I have no idea why this is happening, because the specified file location supposed to be right in both cases.

So my questions are:

- Why I cannot include .js file in this way?
- Which solution I should continue trying to approach (1 or 2)?

[image: structure]

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<!-- 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/touch/sencha-touch.js"></script>
     <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/touch/index.js"></script>  -->

<script>
    var alreadyrunflag = 0 //flag to indicate whether target function has already been run
    var url = "http://www.norwegian.no/";

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

    //on page loaded
    if (document.addEventListener)
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            //alreadyrunflag = 1;
            initGet(url);
        }, false)
    else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
        //page load error?
    }

    function applyChangeEvent() {
        //on selection changed
        var selectDepart = document.getElementById("depart");
        var selectArrive = document.getElementById("arrive");

        selectDepart.onchange = function() { //run some code when "onchange" event fires
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[1].options[document
                    .getElementsByTagName("select")[1].options.selectedIndex].value != ""
                    && document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options[document
                            .getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options.selectedIndex].value != "") {
                for ( var monthsCount = 1; monthsCount < 13; monthsCount++) {
                    //alert(monthsCount);
                    get("http://www.norwegian.no/fly/lavpris/", monthsCount);
                }
            }
        }

        selectArrive.onchange = function() { //run some code when "onchange" event fires
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[1].options[document
                    .getElementsByTagName("select")[1].options.selectedIndex].value != ""
                    && document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options[document
                            .getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options.selectedIndex].value != "") {
                for ( var monthsCount = 1; monthsCount < 13; monthsCount++) {
                    //alert(monthsCount);
                    get("http://www.norwegian.no/fly/lavpris/", monthsCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function initGet(url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                    //request.responseText
                    getObjs(request.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }

    function get(url, month) {
        //alert(month);

        url += "?D_City="
                + document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options[document
                        .getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options.selectedIndex].value;
        url += "&A_City="
                + document.getElementsByTagName("select")[1].options[document
                        .getElementsByTagName("select")[1].options.selectedIndex].value;
        url += "&TripType=1";
        url += "&D_Day=1";
        url += "&D_Month=" + getMonth(month);
        /* url += "&R_Day=1";
        url += "&R_Month=201201"; */
        url += "&AdultCount=1";
        url += "&ChildCount=0";
        url += "&InfantCount=0";

        //alert(url);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                    //request.responseText
                    parse(request.responseText, month);
                }
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }

    function getMonth(month) {
        //alert(month.toString.length + " | " + month);
        if (month.toString().length == 1) {
            var tempMonth = "0" + month.toString();
            //alert(tempMonth);
            return year.toString() + tempMonth;
        } else
            return year.toString() + month;
    }

    function getSimpleMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    function getObjs(mainPageHtml) {
        var mainDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(mainPageHtml,
                "application/xhtml+xml");

        var select = mainDoc.getElementsByTagName("select")[1];
        var options = select.getElementsByTagName("option");

        var citiesArray = [];

        for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

            cityObj = new Object();
            cityObj.name = options[i].text;
            cityObj.value = options[i].value;

            citiesArray.push(cityObj);
        }

        for ( var city = 0; city < citiesArray.length; city++) {
            document.getElementById("depart").innerHTML += "<option value='"+citiesArray[city].value+"'>"
                    + citiesArray[city].name + "</option>";
            document.getElementById("arrive").innerHTML += "<option value='"+citiesArray[city].value+"'>"
                    + citiesArray[city].name + "</option>";
        }

        applyChangeEvent();

    }

    function parse(html, id) {

        var pricesArray = [];

        //alert(id);

        var resultDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html,
                "application/xhtml+xml");

        var divs = resultDoc.getElementsByTagName("table");
        for ( var div = 0; div < divs.length; div++) {
            if (divs[div].className == "fareCalendarTable") {
                //alert("found!");

                // TODO: find out how many to open!!
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("nav_").style.display = "block";

                var table = resultDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")[div];
                var divs = table.getElementsByTagName("div");
                //var tbodyTrs = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

                //alert(document.getElementById("month-one").innerHTML);
                for ( var price = 0; price < divs.length; price++) {
                    if (divs[price].title != "") {

                        /*                      document.getElementById("month-one-results").innerHTML += divs[price].id
                         .replace("OutboundFareCal", "")
                         + " : " + divs[price].title + "<br>"; */

                        priceObj = new Object();
                        priceObj.date = divs[price].id.replace(
                                "OutboundFareCal", "");
                        priceObj.price = divs[price].title.replace(" NOK", "");
                        priceObj.price.replace(/\s/g, '');

                        pricesArray.push(priceObj);
                    }
                }

                /*              pricesArray.sort(function sortNumber(a, b) {
                 return parseInt(b) - parseInt(a);
                 }); */

                for ( var priceUnit = 0; priceUnit < pricesArray.length; priceUnit++) {
                    document.getElementById("month-results-" + id).innerHTML += "<table><tr><td>"
                            + pricesArray[priceUnit].date
                            + "</td><td>"
                            + pricesArray[priceUnit].price
                            + "</td></tr></table>";
                }

            }

            document.getElementById("depart").disabled = "disabled";
            document.getElementById("arrive").disabled = "disabled";
        }

        //  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = bodybox.item(0).innerHTML;
        //holy grail!
        var month = document.getElementById("month-" + id);
        var spans = month.getElementsByTagName("span");

        for ( var span = 0; span < spans.length; span++) {
            if (spans[span].className == "ui-btn-text") {
                spans[span].innerHTML += "<p>" + getCheapest(pricesArray)
                        + "</p>";
            }
        }
    }

    function getCheapest(pricesArray) {
        pricesArray.sort(sort);

        return pricesArray[1].price;
    }

    function sort(a, b) {
        if (a.price < b.price)
            return -1;
        if (a.price > b.price)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    function restart() {
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
        document.getElementById("depart").removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementById("arrive").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
</script>
<style>
body {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #3D3C2F;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif, Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

div#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
    color: #3D3C2F;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif, Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-image:
        url(http://www.norwegian.no/Global/backgrounds/background_no.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-repeat-x: repeat;
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 0%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

div#navigation {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position: block;
    width: 80%;
    background: #CCCC00;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}

select {
    position: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav_" data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="e"
        style="display: none;">
        <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-theme="c"
            onClick="window.location.reload();return false;">Start</a>
        <h1>Ticket Prices</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="navigation">
            Fra/From: <select id="depart">
            </select> Til/To: <select id="arrive">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible" id="1"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-1">January</h3>
            <p id="month-results-1"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="2"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-2">February</h3>
            <p id="month-results-2"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="3"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-3">March</h3>
            <p id="month-results-3"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="4"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-4">April</h3>
            <p id="month-results-4"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="5"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-5">May</h3>
            <p id="month-results-5"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="6"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-6">June</h3>
            <p id="month-results-6"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="7"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-7">July</h3>
            <p id="month-results-7"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="8"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-8">August</h3>
            <p id="month-results-8"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="9"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-9">September</h3>
            <p id="month-results-9"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="10"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-10">October</h3>
            <p id="month-results-10"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="11"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-11">November</h3>
            <p id="month-results-11"></p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="12"
            style="display: none; background: #fff; width: 97%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <h3 id="month-12">December</h3>
            <p id="month-results-12"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div id="results"></div> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure. But phonegap just opens your index.html like a web page. from my experience I'd say it's better to download the files and move them to the sam folder as index.html, maybe a sub-folder and include them by using their relative path. This will make your app bigger, but will shorten your load time.
Also jQuery is slow. Don't use it if you don't *really* need to.

Comment: @MetodMedja I can say that same folder or a child folder of 'www' does not work either. At this point in my application I am just testing how is it working with jQuery, if i'll not fix the problem, then probably will move to Sancha

Comment: @MetodMedja i just want to understand origin of problems described above. Different sources explain different causes of these problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directory structure is assets/www/js/jquery.js use :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: But in this case i don't get any SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///... in log cat, so it is a good start

Comment: You likely have some other structural problem with your project. Are you able to run a PhoneGap project without any jQuery? Are you pointing at the correctly versioned phonegap*.js file? Perhaps you should post your entire index.html file.

Comment: I am able to run project and see the exact results without jquery and i am pointing at the correct file.. i have posted my index.html page in the question

Comment: When I run the index.html file, I get a From and To box on the device and in logcat 01-09 16:47:41.639: E/Web Console(4504): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:131. I had an additional logcat error that went away by putting the jquery.js include before the jquery-mobile.js

Comment: I do not think that these errors are essential for the UI design which jQuery provides. I mean, I did not see any changes at all